# Force protractor script statements to execute sequentially

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In my Protractor script i am calling `browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;` after second statement (after login statement), but it is being applied before login statement since statements are executed in order 1>3>2. below is my code.

```
   browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;//1
   loginPage.login(loginData.free.username,loginData.free.password);//2
   browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;//3
```

However if i use `protractor.promise.controlFlow()` like below then it works fine. But how to force protractor scripts to execute sequentially without using `protractor.promise.controlFlow()`.

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
    flow.execute(function () {
        loginPage.login(loginData.free.username,loginData.free.password);               
        browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;
    }
```

Comment: var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow(); does this necessary to use?

Comment: @SureshSalloju if i don't use `var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();` i am getting '"window.angular is undefined.' error

Comment: Can you put browser.ignoreSynchronization= true; this statement in beforeAll() method if your using jasmine. It should be declared before calling browser.get() method

Comment: @SureshSalloju yeah, I think you are correct and you should put this statement as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, i will do it

Answer (score 2):

Put 'browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;' statement in beforeAll() method if your using jasmine. It should be declared before calling browser.get() and also declare 'browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;' statement after login operation.

**Code Snippet:**

```
 beforeAll(function(){
     browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
     browser.get('url');
  }); 

 it('test logic',function(){
    loginPage.login(loginData.free.username,loginData.free.password);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;
 });
```